# How to find the background color of the text using itextsharp

Tags: itext

I am able to find the foreground color of the text using itxtsharp (renderInfo.GetFillColor()), is it possible to find the background color of the text using itextsharp.i.e. Some of the text in the PDF file are inside the color box, i need to skip the text that are present inside the color box, is it possible. Please advice on this. Thanks in advance.

```
//Used to get the foreground color of the text
BaseColor curColor = new BaseColor(0f, 0f, 0f);
 if (renderInfo.GetFillColor() != null)
  curColor = renderInfo.GetFillColor();
```

Comment: It's not easy to do that. You seem to use the itext parser classes. You will have to extend them to also forward information on vector graphics as the most common way to create a colored background is to fill vector path, e.g. a rectangle, and the parser classes currently do not process these vector operations.

Comment: Just to further elaborate on what @mkl said, PDFs don't have a concept of "background color". Anything that "looks" like a background color is really just text that "happens to be on top" of something else that "happens to be there". That "something" is probably a vector path as noted. To get the color you'd need to get the rectangle for the given text and examine shapes underneath it.