# Read PDF cell which is in fill color

Tags: c#, .net, itext, pdftotext

How to read PDF cell color ???

I am parsing and getting text data from PDF file, It has Status column where value of that column is in color. So I wanted to get the color code or some way to read the status.

I am using iTextSharp dll.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This will not be as easy as you might think. From a PDF's perspective there are no "tables" or "cells" or "background colors" (or "paragraphs" and "words" even). Instead, what you think of as a table is a bunch of text drawn at consistent locations with lines drawn around the text. There's no relationship between the text and the lines why is why there is no "cell" in the first place. The "fill color" of a the lines is either the fill color of the shape of the lines or just a rectangle drawn behind the lines. See the comment here for a little more http://stackoverflow.com/q/19762372/231316

Comment: You seem to indicate that the PDFs you have are of a specific type only. If that indeed is the case, please provide a sample document. Probably there is an easy way for your specific files. If it is not the case, I am completely with @Chris.